# Encounter "Error Unable to alter table." when alter table column positons in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a simple table `fiction_movie`:

```
hive>describe fiction_movie;
OK
title string
actors array<string>
genre string
rating int
4 rows selected (0.03 seconds)
```

content in table:

```
hive> select * from fiction_movie;
OK
avatar  ["zoe saldana","Sam worthington"]   science fiction  7
logan  ["hugh jackman","Patrick stewart"]   science fiction  8
2 rows selected (0.352 seconds)
```

What I want to do is to rearrange column positions and put title after genre:

```
#I tried
hive>alter table fiction_movie change column title title string after genre;
```

But it gave me the following error:

> Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. The following columns have types incompatible with the existing columns in their respective positions :
>   actors,genre (state=08S01,code=1)

Does anyone know why? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is perfectly working in my machine.

```
hive> create table fiction_movie(
    > title string,
    > actors array<string>,
    > genre string,
    > rating int);
OK
Time taken: 0.155 seconds
hive> alter table fiction_movie change column title title string after genre;
OK
Time taken: 0.4 seconds
hive> describe  fiction_movie;
OK
actors                  array<string>
genre                   string
title                   string
rating                  int
Time taken: 0.37 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Or try to set this property.
You can force hive to allow you to change it by using:

```
`SET hive.metastore.disallow.invalid.col.type.changes=true;`
```

than alter your table.

Comment: Is '`SET hive.metastore.disallow.invalid.col.type.changes=true;` ' proper configuration setting?. From the hive [wiki|https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.metastore.disallow.incompatible.col.type.changes], i see only "hive.metastore.disallow.incompatible.col.type.changes". Please correct it.